Google Sheets addon showing 'Help' menu instead or authorization?
When I submitted my Google Sheets add-on code for approval, the validation feedback only mentioned seeing a 'Help' menu for our new extension. I've reviewed the code, but I'm finding it hard to pinpoint the issue. What can I look at next?

"Menu - Menu options not shown after App is installed. Please ensure
that the add-on correctly uses onInstall() and onOpen() to populate
its menu. The menu items populate when the add-on is first installed
and when a different file is opened. See Editor add-on authorization.
,
https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle"

Code:
    function onInstall(e) {
      onOpen(e);
    }
    
    function onOpen(e) {
      if(e && e.authMode == ScriptApp.AuthMode.NONE){
        showAuthorizationAlert();
        return;
      }else{
        const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
        const menu = ui.createAddonMenu();
        addStandardMenuItems(menu);
        markPromptFormulas();
        menu.addToUi();
      }
    }
    
    function showAuthorizationAlert() {
      const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      ui.alert('Authorization Required', 'Please authorize this add-on to enable full functionality.', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
      authorizeAddon();
    }
    
    function authorizeAddon() {
      try {
        const userEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
        const userProfile = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo');
        const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
        ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
        const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request');
        const sheets = ss.getSheets();
        const readOnly = ss.getRange('A1').getValue();
      } catch (e) {
        Logger.log('Authorization failed: ' + e.toString());
      }
    }
    
    function addStandardMenuItems(menu) {
        menu
          .addItem('ㅤSheet Library', 'openSheetLibrarySidebar')
          .addItem('⚙️ㅤSheet Settings', 'showSettingsSidebar')
          .addToUi();
      }
    }


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/9dixEHKN.png


This question is similar to: Cannot publish the google editor addon due to "Menu options not shown after App is installed..." error. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
